# Objective-c specific iOS version in @interface

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement Apple Pay, and I try to implement 2 methods one for iOS10 and one for iOS11+,

So in my implementation I have:

```
-(void) paymentAuthorizationViewController
  (PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                                   didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                                               handler:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationResult * _Nonnull))completion  API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0))
        {
       self.completionResult = completion
            ...

- (void) paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                                    didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                                             completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus))completion 
            {
      self.completionStatus = completion
        ...
```

And in my interface I have:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionStatus)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus);
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionResult)(PKPaymentAuthorizationResult *);
```

The issue I have is XCode give me the following warning in the interface:

```
'PKPaymentAuthorizationResult' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer
```

Is it a correct way to implement version specific code?  Can I specify version specific code in interfaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To silent the warning in the interface you can try to add the API_AVAILABLE macros like this: `API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0))` at the end of the declaration.

Comment: Thanks I added it `@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionResult)(PKPaymentAuthorizationResult *) API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0));
` and now the interface does not complain.

I already have that bit in the first `paymentAuthorizationViewController ` and it works on ios11, I haven't tried it yet on ios10.

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted if you remove the first bit, because my question was regarding the interface, if it is ok with you?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this as well I believe.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionResult)(PKPaymentAuthorizationResult *) API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Could not accept your answer because you were just a few seconds late compare to the other answer.